# Formik: how to set initial values from array?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have customer objects that have an array of credit cards associated with them, like this:

```
{
  "_id":"5d63e3a32f093f2b5e41ef96", 
  "firstName": <firstName>,
  "lastName": <lastName>,
  "email": <email>,
  "createdAt":"2019-08-26T13:50:27.409Z",
  "modifiedAt":"2019-09-14T20:10:00.257Z",
  "paymentMethods":[{
    "name": <name>, 
    "last4": <last4>, 
    "expirationDate": <expDate>,
    "isDefault":false,
    "token": <token>
  }, {
    "name": <name>, 
    "last4": <last4>, 
    "expirationDate": <expDate>,
    "isDefault":false,
    "token": <token>
  }, {
    "name": <name>, 
    "last4": <last4>, 
    "expirationDate": <expDate>,
    "isDefault":false,
    "token": <token>
  }
}
```

I want to set initial values in formik.  Like this:

```
const INITIAL_VALUES = {
  firstName: customer.firstName,
  lastName: customer.lastName,
  email: customer.email,
  phoneNumber: customer.phone,
  paymentMethods: ???????
};
```

I want to be able to edit the payment method information.  I can draw the form so that the fields all appear the right number of times, but how do I set initial values with formik?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a `initialValues` prop that you pass to formik. You might want to read the docs

Comment: Can you show what have you done so far which is not working where you need help with?

Comment: @sagar.acharya I'm aware of the `initialValues` prop.  My question is how do I specify the array values when there could be 0 to many paymentMethods.

Comment: @Rikin I've tried the obvious `paymentMethods:  customer.paymentMethods` in the `INITIAL_VALUES` object, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

formik has an initialValues prop that you can pass an object that each key represents the value of the input.

I guess you are using a custom input for paymentMethods that returns an array of selected methods as a callback so it should accept an array as initialValues then you can simply pass formik values[inputName] to your custom input and in your INITIAL_VALUES object you can pass array itself

Comment: I'm already using `initialValues`, like so: `<Formik initialValues={INITIAL_VALUES}... />`  My question is how to specify the initial values for the paymentMethods array.  `paymentMethods:  customer.paymentMethods` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly specify the initialValues: `<Formik initialValues={INITIAL_VALUES} />`. Then when you render the form inside `<Formik />`, you can access and render the `paymentMethods` like:

```
formikProps.values.paymentMethods.map((method, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <input
      name={`paymentMethods.${index}.name`}
      value={method.name}
      onChange={formikProps.handleChange}
    />
    {/* Render other fields for each paymentMethod*/}
  </div>
))
```

You can also use FieldArray to render array of objects (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray)

Comment: I think this answer doesn't relate to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `initialValues` for the `paymentMethods` like this:

```
const INITIAL_VALUES = {
  //initial values for other fields here
  paymentMethods: customer.paymentMethods,
};
```

See example from the official docs: https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays